# Tensorflow classify_image

Tags: python, r, shiny

This shiny app is built from: [here](https://github.com/yukiegosapporo/2016-01-12-mini-ai-app-using-tensorflow-and-shiny)
It basically uses tensorflow python in R shiny. My main question is getting the py code to run in R.

Edit: I managed to make it run by making some changes. Everything runs.  However, there is no wordcloud, nor can i get the output printed on shiny. After uploading the image, the output will be in Rstudio's console.

```
library(wordcloud)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    PYTHONPATH <- "C:/Program Files/Anaconda3"  #should look like /Users/yourname/anaconda/bin if you use anaconda python distribution in OS X
    CLASSIFYIMAGEPATH <- "C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet" #should look like ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet

    outputtext <- reactive({
      ###This is to compose image recognition template###
      inFile <- input$file1 #This creates input button that enables image upload
      template <- paste0("python"," ", "classify_image.py") #Template to run image recognition using Python
      if (is.null(inFile))
        {system(paste0(template," --image_file /tmp/imagenet/cropped_panda.jpg"))} else { #Initially the app classifies cropped_panda.jpg, if you download the model data to a different directory, you should change /tmp/imagenet to the location you use. 
      system(paste0(template," --image_file ",inFile$datapath)) #Uploaded image will be used for classification
        }



      })

    output$answer <- renderPrint({outputtext()})

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ###This is to create wordcloud based on image recognition results###
      df <- data.frame(gsub(" *\\(.*?\\) *", "", outputtext()),gsub("[^0-9.]", "", outputtext())) #Make a dataframe using detected objects and scores
      names(df) <- c("Object","Score") #Set column names
      df$Object <- as.character(df$Object) #Convert df$Object to character
      df$Score <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Score)) #Convert df$Score to numeric
      s <- strsplit(as.character(df$Object), ',') #Split rows by comma to separate rows
      df <- data.frame(Object=unlist(s), Score=rep(df$Score, sapply(s, FUN=length))) #Allocate scores to split words
      # By separating long categories into shorter terms, we can avoid "could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted" warning as much as possible
      wordcloud(df$Object, df$Score, scale=c(4,2),
                    colors=brewer.pal(6, "RdBu"),random.order=F) #Make wordcloud
    })

    output$outputImage <- renderImage({
      ###This is to plot uploaded image###
      if (is.null(input$file1)){
        outfile <- "/tmp/imagenet/cropped_panda.jpg"
        contentType <- "image/jpg"
        #Panda image is the default
      }else{
        outfile <- input$file1$datapath
        contentType <- input$file1$type
        #Uploaded file otherwise
        }

      list(src = outfile,
           contentType=contentType,
           width=300)
    }, deleteFile = TRUE)
})
```

Example of output on Rstudio's console:

> pug, pug-dog (score = 0.89841) bull mastiff (score = 0.01825)
>   Brabancon griffon (score = 0.01114) French bulldog (score = 0.00161)
>   Pekinese, Pekingese, Peke (score = 0.00091) W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_def_util.cc:332]
>   Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to
>   work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().

Does anyone knows what is going on? I tried various methods, but i cant get the output printed (used renderPrint, rendertext... etc)

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes i am sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

OK here are two ways -

**1**

a. Install RPython for windows [Linux/Mac from CRAN]. Download as zip [Clone/Download as zip option] - https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win

b. Unzip it, rename the folder to rPython, Change configure.win to point to your python installation [it must be the Anaconda I guess]

c. Execute the code in R -

```
library(devtools) # devtools needs to be installed - install.packages("devtools")
install("C:/Users/username/Downloads/rPython") # location where you have downloaded rPython
```

My output -

```
Installing rPython
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
  INSTALL "C:/Users/vk046010/Downloads/rPython"  \
  --library="C:/Users/vk046010/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'rPython' ...
** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"  -I"C:/Anaconda2/include"   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c pycall.c -o pycall.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rPython.dll tmp.def pycall.o -LC:/Anaconda2/libs -lpython27 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/vk046010/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rPython/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rPython)
```

d. Now execute this from RStudio -

```
# tensorflow caller
library("rPython")


py_code <- "
def classify_image(image_loc): 
  # load tensorflow and predict here
  return image_loc+'person' # return the result here
"
python.exec(py_code)

python.call( "classify_image", 'path/loc/to/image/')
```

The output of python.call should be the thing you are looking for.

**2**

I haven't done this before so no personal guarantees. You can install tensorflow in R itself - https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow

Comment: Hi vivek, how do i go about changing the config.win. i got this error compilation terminated.
make: *** [pycall.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "D:/R-3.3.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "D:/R-3.3.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="rPython.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="pycall.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rPython'
* removing 'D:/R-3.3.2/library/rPython'
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Change `echo 'PKG_LIBS=-LC:/python27/libs -lpython27'  > src/makevars.win
echo 'PKG_CFLAGS=-I"C:/Python27/include"'     >> src/makevars.win` to where your python is installed